# Как сделать спрайт SVG, чтобы при добавлении его в адаптивную страничку HTML, иконки не выходили за границы своих контейнеров.

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, svg-спрайт

**Более развернуто, что я хочу получить в результате:**

- Как выбирать и дорабатывать изображения `SVG` (иконки в частности) 
  для включения в спрайт.
- Какая должна быть структура и настройки спрайта, для того чтобы:
  была возможность при однократном добавлении спрайта использовать его
  компоненты во многих местах HTML страниц
- была возможность стилизации иконок из внешней таблицы `CSS`

  **Требования к иконкам:**
- Иконки SVG должны быть масштабируемыми, то есть должны уменьшаться,
  увеличиваться  при уменьшении, увеличении окна просмотра гаджета, при
  этом не выходить за границы своего контейнера.
- Иконки должны менять цвет при наведении курсора
- Иконки должны при необходимости выступать в роли ссылки

На картинке ниже макет того, что я хочу получить в результате

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Как выбирать и дорабатывать изображения SVG**

Иконки нарисованные в векторных редакторах: Inkscape, Adobe Illustrator и других, как правило требуют оптимизации для уменьшения веса и получения более понятного кода для последующей ручной доработки.

Мне нравится [svg-editor](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor) от Peter Collingridge, который очень прост для освоения и работает очень эффективно, снижая вес файла иконки в несколько раз.

Для спрайта лучше всего подбирать иконки с одинаковыми параметрами: одноцветные, с линиями выполненными с помощью только  `<path>` или только `<polygon>`.
 `<line>`и `<rect>` необходимо преобразовывать в `<path>`.
Также необходимо, чтобы у  выбранных иконок были одинаковые  `viewBox`
Например: `viewBox="0 0 126 126"`
Пример иконки, которая будет использована в спрайте, смотри ниже

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  width="126" height="126" viewBox="0 0 126 126" >
  <path d="M113.5 57.7l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 22.1l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9L20.5 48l-8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 66 116.2 61.2 113.5 57.7zM63.1 102c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4s16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4 37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4S83.7 102 63.1 102zM63.1 30.8c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8s33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 46 81.7 30.8 63.1 30.8zM64.6 42.6c1.8-2.1 4.8-3.6 7.2-3.7 0.3 2.9-0.8 5.8-2.6 7.9 -1.7 2.1-4.5 3.7-7.3 3.5C61.6 47.4 63 44.4 64.6 42.6zM78.7 82c-2.1 3-4.2 6-7.5 6 -3.3 0.1-4.4-2-8.1-2 -3.8 0-4.9 1.9-8.1 2 -3.2 0.1-5.7-3.2-7.8-6.2 -4.2-6.1-7.5-17.3-3.1-24.8 2.2-3.7 6-6.1 10.2-6.2 3.2-0.1 6.2 2.1 8.1 2.1 1.9 0 5.6-2.6 9.4-2.3 1.6 0.1 6.1 0.6 9 4.9 -0.2 0.2-5.4 3.1-5.3 9.4 0.1 7.4 6.5 9.9 6.6 10C82.1 75.1 81.1 78.5 78.7 82z"/>
</svg>
```

В шапке SVG файла **необходимо убрать** - `width="126" height="126"` - это `viewport`, который мешает  иконке была адаптивной. То есть иконка должна целиком занимать родительский контейнер `<div id="container>` и при резиновой верстке изменять свой размер вместе с контейнером при изменении окна просмотра гаджета.

Атрибуты патчей - `style=" fill:` `stroke:` `stroke-width:"`тоже необходимо убрать, так как они имеют наивысший приоритет и не могут быть изменены из внешней таблицы стилей `CSS`.

**Какая должна быть структура и настройки спрайта**

Главная задача спрайта - быть хранилищем для иконок, которые до вызова в определенное место HTML странички должны быть невидимыми.

Это реализуется двумя способами:

1. код каждой иконки помещается внутри группового тега `<g id=".."> .... </g>` и всё вместе размещается в секции `<defs>... </defs>`
2. Код каждой иконки оборачивается тегами 
   `<symbol id="..">...</symbol>` с присвоением уникального идентификатора, по которому в дальнейшем будет вызов иконки командой `<use>`

Чаще пользуются вторым способом.
Пример структуры спрайта.

```
<div id="container1"> 
  <svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   viewBox="0 0 126 126" >
  <symbol id="picasa">
        <path     d="M113.5 57.... 72.8z" /> 
  </symbol>

     <symbol id="wordpress"  viewBox="0 0 126 126"> 
       <path stroke ="black"  d="M113.5 57.7l-8.5-11.4 .. 86.1 62.9z"/>
     </symbol>

       <symbol id="twitter">
          <path d="M113.5 57.6l-8.5-11.4.... 7.4-2.4V85.4z"/>
       </symbol>
  <symbol id="apple">
     <path d="M113.5 57.7l-8.5-11.4... 78.5 78.7 82z"/>
  </symbol>
</div>
```

Как видим убраны все атрибуты `<path>` для последующей стилизации иконок из внешнего файла `CSS`.
И обратите внимание, что к иконке с `id="wordpress"` добавлен дополнительный `viewBox`

`<symbol id="wordpress"  viewBox="0 0 126 126">`

Это делается для выравнивания размеров иконки, отличающимися от размеров других иконок. Параметр необязательный, но очень полезный, не только для подгонки размеров, но и центрирования иконки внутри.

**Добавление файла спрайта в HTML**

Есть [несколько способов](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047) добавления файлов `SVG` в `HTML`, но самым надежным является добавление посредством тега `<object>`

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="Sprite.svg" width="200" height="200">
  Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

**Добавление иконок из спрайта**

```
<div id="container2"> 
     <svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 126 126" >

        <use xlink:href="#apple"></use>  
   </svg>
</div>
```

Блок SVG обернут дивом контейнера. Для надежности добавляйте всегда `Namespace` SVG -  `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`

**Иконки в качестве ссылок**

Для этого в SVG, в отличии от HTML, своя форма записи:

```
 <svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 126 126" >

        <a xlink:href="https://www.apple.com/ru/"><use xlink:href="#apple"></use></a>  
</svg>
```

Поэтому надо добавлять `Namespace` `SVG`, без этой строчки работать не будет.

**Стилизация иконок**

При использовании команды `<use>` иконка попадает в `shadow DOM` и её атрибуты ведут себя странно,- экземпляр иконки есть, но она не поддается управлению извне. Кроме того атрибуты иконки например: style="fill:grey; stroke:cromson;"  имеют наивысший приоритет. Поэтому мы удалили эти атрибуты. см. пример спрайта выше.
Для решения проблемы  наследования родительских свойств объектами в shadow Dom необходимо применить принудительное наследование `inherit`

```
svg path{
fill:inherit;
 stroke:inherit;
 }
```

и далее к иконкам уже можно применять правила `CSS` из внешней таблицы

```
svg path:hover{fill:yellow;} 

       #picasa{fill:black;}   /* greenyellow */
       #apple{fill:purple;}
       #twitter{fill:black;}         /* dodgerblue */
       #wordpress{fill:blue;}
```

Теперь собираем всё вместе:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <style>
  body{ background: linear-gradient(to top, #85FFB0 , #7FCAFF);}    
  .page{ margin: 1% 1%;padding:25% 1% 5% 1%;  width:100%; height:auto; position:relative;  }
 .square {
float:left;
position: relative;
width: 22.5%;
height:auto;
padding-bottom: 22.5%; 
margin:0.25%;
overflow:hidden;
}

.container1, .container2, .container3, .container4
{padding:1% 3%; position:absolute; }

.container1 {bottom:5%;   background-color:#54E281;}  
 .container2 {bottom:5%;   background-color:#CDF333;} 
  .container3 {bottom:5%;   background-color:#FFAB1B;} 
    .container4 {bottom:5%;  background-color:#E571FF;} 
   svg path{fill:inherit;}  
   
  
  path:hover{fill:yellow; stroke:black;  pointer-events:all;} 
  
  #picasa{fill:black;}  
   #apple{fill:purple;}
   #twitter{fill:black;}        
   #wordpress{fill:blue;}
  
 </style>
 <body>

 <div class="page"> 
   <div class="square">
<div class="container1"> 
  <svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"    width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 126 126" >
  
   <symbol id="picasa">
    <path     d="M113.5 57.7l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 22.1l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9L20.5 48l-8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 66 116.2 61.2 113.5 57.7zM63.1 102c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4s16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4 37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4S83.7 102 63.1 102zM63.1 30.8c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8 18.7 0 33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 46 81.7 30.8 63.1 30.8zM63.1 40.1c3.5 0 6.9 0.8 10.2 2.2 0 0.3 0 15.3 0 16.4 -0.8-0.8-18.1-16.4-18.8-17C57.3 40.6 60.1 40.1 63.1 40.1zM38.5 64.7c0-9.3 5.1-17.7 13.4-21.9 0.3 0.3 8.9 8.1 9.3 8.5 -0.4 0.4-21.2 19.2-21.8 19.8C38.8 69 38.5 66.8 38.5 64.7zM50.4 85.7c-4.6-2.8-8.2-7-10.2-11.9 0.3-0.3 9.4-8.5 10.2-9.2C50.4 65.7 50.4 84.8 50.4 85.7zM65.3 89.2h-4.5c-2.7-0.2-5.3-0.9-7.8-2.1 0-0.4 0-11.2 0-11.7 0.5 0 31.3 0 32.2 0C81.4 83.2 73.8 88.4 65.3 89.2zM86.3 72.8c-0.4 0-10 0-10.5 0 0-0.5 0-28.1 0-29.1 7.3 4.5 11.9 12.4 11.9 21C87.7 67.4 87.2 70.2 86.3 72.8z" />

</symbol>
 <symbol id="wordpress">

  <path stroke ="black"  d="M113.5 57.7l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 22.1l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9L20.5 48l-8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 66 116.2 61.2 113.5 57.7zM63.1 102c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4s16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4 37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4S83.7 102 63.1 102zM63.7 67.6L53.5 97.3c3.1 0.9 6.3 1.4 9.6 1.4 4 0 7.8-0.7 11.3-1.9 -0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5L63.7 67.6zM80.2 94.1c10.1-5.9 16.9-16.9 16.9-29.5 0-5.9-1.5-11.5-4.2-16.4 0.2 1.1 0.2 2.3 0.2 3.5 0 3.5-0.6 7.3-2.6 12.2L80.2 94.1zM29 64.6c0 13.5 7.8 25.2 19.2 30.7L31.9 50.8C30.1 55 29 59.7 29 64.6zM86.1 62.9c0-4.2-1.5-7.1-2.8-9.4 -1.7-2.8-3.3-5.2-3.3-8 0-3.1 2.4-6 5.7-6 0.1 0 0.3 0 0.4 0 -6.1-5.6-14.1-9-23-9 -11.9 0-22.4 6.1-28.5 15.4 0.8 0 1.6 0 2.2 0 3.6 0 9.1-0.4 9.1-0.4 1.8-0.1 2.1 2.6 0.2 2.8 0 0-1.8 0.2-3.9 0.3l12.4 36.9 7.5-22.4L56.8 48.7c-1.8-0.1-3.6-0.3-3.6-0.3 -1.8-0.1-1.6-2.9 0.2-2.8 0 0 5.6 0.4 9 0.4 3.6 0 9.1-0.4 9.1-0.4 1.8-0.1 2.1 2.6 0.2 2.8 0 0-1.8 0.2-3.9 0.3l12.3 36.6 3.4-11.4C85.2 69.5 86.1 65.8 86.1 62.9z"/>

</symbol>
   <symbol id="twitter">

  <path d="M113.5 57.6l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 21.9l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9l-2 14.1 -8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 65.9 116.2 61.1 113.5 57.6zM63.1 101.9c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4 0-20.6 16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4s37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4C100.4 85.1 83.7 101.9 63.1 101.9zM63.1 30.7c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8 18.7 0 33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 45.9 81.7 30.7 63.1 30.7zM78.5 85.4c-2.1 1-4 1.7-5.7 2.1s-3.5 0.6-5.5 0.6c-2.2 0-3.6-0.3-5.3-0.8 -1.7-0.6-3.2-1.4-4.4-2.4 -1.2-1.1-2.1-2.2-2.5-3.4 -0.5-1.2-0.7-2.9-0.7-5.2V59.1h-6.7v-7c1.9-0.6 4.2-1.5 5.6-2.7 1.4-1.2 2.5-2.6 3.3-4.2 0.8-1.6 1.4-3.7 1.7-6.3h7v11.4h11.4v8.8H65.2v12.6c0 2.9 0 4.5 0.3 5.3 0.3 0.8 1.1 1.6 1.9 2.1 1.1 0.7 2.3 1 3.7 1 2.5 0 5-0.8 7.4-2.4V85.4z"/>

  </symbol>
  <symbol id="apple">

  <path d="M113.5 57.7l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 22.1l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9L20.5 48l-8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 66 116.2 61.2 113.5 57.7zM63.1 102c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4s16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4 37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4S83.7 102 63.1 102zM63.1 30.8c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8s33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 46 81.7 30.8 63.1 30.8zM64.6 42.6c1.8-2.1 4.8-3.6 7.2-3.7 0.3 2.9-0.8 5.8-2.6 7.9 -1.7 2.1-4.5 3.7-7.3 3.5C61.6 47.4 63 44.4 64.6 42.6zM78.7 82c-2.1 3-4.2 6-7.5 6 -3.3 0.1-4.4-2-8.1-2 -3.8 0-4.9 1.9-8.1 2 -3.2 0.1-5.7-3.2-7.8-6.2 -4.2-6.1-7.5-17.3-3.1-24.8 2.2-3.7 6-6.1 10.2-6.2 3.2-0.1 6.2 2.1 8.1 2.1 1.9 0 5.6-2.6 9.4-2.3 1.6 0.1 6.1 0.6 9 4.9 -0.2 0.2-5.4 3.1-5.3 9.4 0.1 7.4 6.5 9.9 6.6 10C82.1 75.1 81.1 78.5 78.7 82z"/>

  </symbol>
  <a xlink:href="http://picasa.google.com/"><use xlink:href="#picasa"></use></a>
</svg>
  </div>
</div> 
  <div class="square">
<div class="container2"> 
  <svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"   width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 126 126" >  
 
  <a xlink:href="https://www.apple.com/ru/"><use xlink:href="#apple"></use></a>  -->
 </svg>
</div>  
  </div>
<div class="square">
   <div class="container3"> 
  <svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 126 126">
       <a xlink:href="https://twitter.com/?lang=ru"><use xlink:href="#twitter"></use></a>
     </svg>
  </div> 
</div>
  <div class="square">
   <div class="container4"> 
 <svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 126 126" >
   <a xlink:href="https://ru.wordpress.org/"><use xlink:href="#wordpress"></use></a>
 </svg>
   </div> 

 </div>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

- Ссылки на иконках рабочие, при клике будет осуществлен переход на
  соответствующий ресурс. (видимо политика безопасности сниппета запрещает переход на внешние ресурсы из окна выполнения сниппета)
- Только в FF при наведении ссылки подсвечиваются
- страничка адаптивна, пробуйте изменять величину окна просмотра