# Как использовать формат svg как основное блюдо?

Tags: css, css3, svg, svg-спрайт

Добрый день! Много уже читал про формат svg, но так и не совсем понял, как лучше выполнить svg спрайты. У меня возникли следующие вопросы.

Нужно ли сейчас дублировать спрайты в формате png для тех браузеров, которые не понимают svg?

И второй вопрос: если, допустим, на сайте используется иконка размером 50х50 пикселей (используем ее как фоновый рисунок), мы ее добавляем в спрайт в этом размере в формате png, и в этом же размере нам нужно ее добавлять в спрайт в формате svg, и при увеличении она будет смотреться четко? Правильно я понимаю?

И тут же рождается у меня еще один вопрос: такие иконки, как лупа, гамбургер, крестик, различные стрелки - и все же в каком формате их лучше выполнять, в svg и css?

Одним словом, я себе таким образом усложнил жизнь. Может быть, конечно, вопросы глупые, но хоть убейте, прочитав различные статьи (кстати почему-то как ни открою, так они обязательно несколько летней давности) про формат svg, так и не сложил у себя в голове окончательно картинку, как все же правильно использовать этот формат. Не пинайте, не отправляйте читать матчасть, а дайте здесь дельные советы. Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Нужно ли сейчас дублировать спрайты в формате png для тех браузеров,
>   которые не понимают svg?

В основном не нужно дублировать спрайты форматом png, так как даже IE начал понимать svg, кроме анимации. Но в этом случае, тем более не выручит png :-)

> И тут же рождается у меня еще один вопрос: такие иконки, как лупа,
>   гамбургер, крестик, различные стрелки - и все же в каком формате их
>   лучше выполнять, в svg и css?

Это остается на ваш выбор, как лучше у вас получается, так и делайте.

- Svg иконки по определению весят меньше, чем иконки png.
- Svg масштабируется без потери качества, а png нет.
- Но, чтобы работать с SVG необходимо понимать этот формат, иначе будет
  много вопросов типа: почему не масштабируется, почему  иконки svg
  не стилизуются и т.д и т.п

Из текста вашего вопроса я понял, что вам не хотелось бы учить матчасть, но как дать "дельные советы" не опираясь на теорию и практику. Вот некоторые ссылки, где очень кратко описана теория и практика работы с SVG:

[Как заставить масштабироваться квадраты-svg?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657480/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-svg)

[Как выбирать и дорабатывать изображения SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657213/28748)

[Как взаимодействуют между собой viewport и viewBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748)

Последняя ссылка - это фундамент для понимания SVG
При понимании этих основ исчезнут вопросы типа:

- почему svg изображение обрезается?
- почему не масштабируется?
- почему svg иконки вообще не видно?
- как иконку позиционировать?

Comment: @ с появлением современных гаджетов SVG переживает вторую молодость. На мой взгляд интерфейс веб страничек должен быть целиком векторным, а растр должен остаться только для картинок. Если вам мой ответ помог, отметьте его пожалуйста галочкой

Comment: @LADYX кстати не обращайте внимание на дату статей о SVG. так как Svg, не менялся с 2001 года, правда были незначительные изменения в 2008 году - вышла версия 1.1  Версия SVG2 только готовится к выпуску и уже так много лет. Поэтому все статьи, за любую дату, практически актуальны